What is a best way to remove hair from my head model
I got a model of Geralt's from Witcher head, but essentially I need him bald - is there any efficient way to remove the hair (so that I can easily sculpt it to the skull shape afterwards?). Object and edit mode:



An electric shaver usually works well. Are they separate mesh chunks? If not I seen no way other than deleting manually
